# ASP.NET Core AntiForgery - Get detailed logs from ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I implemented the AntiForgery strategy from Microsoft in my ASP.NET core application with Angular. Everything works fine but occasionally I see an error in my log file that indicates that the validation of the token failed and my controller returned a 400. Right now the application is not accessible from the outside and every request should be legitimate so this worries me.

Is it possible to get more information from the "ValidateAntiForgeryToken" attribute when the validation fails? Is there something that I can do to tell the attribute to be more talkative/informative? I tried to inherit from the attribute but there are no virtual methods that I can override.

I don't know what I can do to get more information to solve this problem.

Comment: This usually happens (in my experience) for one of two reasons. a) The user logged out in another tab. b) ASP.NET generated a new antiforgery token.

Comment: @mjwills but why should ASP.NET generate a new token? and why should the old token be invalid because of that? My encryption key for the tokens is in a database and if you had a valid token at one point it should be still valid even if a new token has been generated.